# How to get the parent element of marked text inside div element with contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Every time I try it gives me a `p` tag even doe the parent should be a `span`

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
console.log(sel.getRangeAt(0));
```

Is there any solution or a way to do it or got a link to some useful information how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `range` properties [startContainer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/startContainer), [endContainer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/endContainer) and [commonAncestorContainer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/commonAncestorContainer) to determine the selection containing elements.
In the following example select the text "bbb" and press the button "press me". The `commonAncestorContainer` is `span` element as expected:

```js
$('#pressme').click(function(){
  var rng = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  alert(rng.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.tagName);
});
```

```css
#editor {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='editor' contenteditable='true'>aaa <span style="color:red">bbb</span> ccc</div>
<input id='pressme' type='button' value='press me' />
```

Try to select various portions of text and see how it changes the result.

Comment: Hey Alexander,

Thanks for your answer I already tried that and it return me the P tag but, after doing it again I found out that childNodes may contain the answer, so thanks :)

Comment: My pleasure to help :) Please vote my answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Found a better way for what I wanted to accomplish :)

Here Is a small sample for people who are searching for something similar :)
$(sel.focusNode).children()